# WPF, ListBox, использующий шаблон данных, не срабатывает событие SelectionChanged

Tags: wpf, listbox

WPF - форма, на ней ListBox.
В нём создаю шаблон данных.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Width="175">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource RadioButtons}" />
            <Button Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Проблема в том, что при выборе элементов списка событие SelectionChanged срабатывает
только если я нажимаю мимо RadioButton и Button в шаблоне элемента.
Кликаю где-нибудь на самом краю - работает.
Жму непосредственно кнопки в шаблоне элемента - событие списка не работает.
От того, что я использую стиль - не зависит.
Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется, решил:

- когда срабатывает событие элемета шаблона данных (например RadioButton)
  нужно подняться вверх по визуальному дереву, пока не найду содержащий его ListBoxItem.
- а потом установить его свойство IsSelected в true, тогда сработает и событие Listbox'a.

Так я узнал, что такое визуальное дерево!